# How to convert assets folders to ArrayList<Object>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, assets

I'm trying to create an ArrayList according to my assets folder.
So, i have a Person class

```
public class Person{
             String Name;
             String[] images;
             String[] songs;
    }
```

my assets structure look like that:

- assetes

  - Persons

    - Mike

      - imageOfMike1.jpg
      - imageOfMike2.jpg

        - Songs

          - mikeSong.wav
    - Linda

      - imageOfLinda1.jpg
      - imageOfLinda2.jpg

        - Songs

          - LindaSong.wav

How can i filter all assetes folder by person names and convert it to a nice ArrayList of Person including there names?

I found a way to get all asstest list file by:

```
private boolean listAssetFiles(String path) {
    String [] list;
    try {
        list = getAssets().list("Persons");
        if (list.length > 0) {
            // This is a folder
            for (String file : list) {
                if (!listAssetFiles(path + "/" + file))
                    return false;
            }
        } else {
            // This is a file
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```